# Display locks up when using laptop display and nvidia-337 from xorg-edgers, ctrl-alt-f1 breaks me out

Tags: gnome, nvidia

Kind of a generic question but I don't really know what's relevant to the problem.

I'm using a T430s laptop when a Nvidia Optimus setup (intel + nvidia GPUs). It works perfectly when the laptop is in its dock with the lid closed driving two external monitors. However, if I remove the laptop from the dock after about 20 minutes of use the display completely locks up (no mouse cursor movement at all). Hitting ctrl-alt-f1 breaks out and from there I can run `sudo restart lightdm` to get my normal window environment back.

I'm using the xorg-edgers ppa and the nvidia-337 drivers.

Any ideas? Which logs can I check?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling the nvidia drivers with `apt-get remove nvidia*` or `apt-get purge nvidia*` will re-enable the nouveau drivers. I've had similar issues and had to check a few versions of the driver before I found one that actually worked on my system.